# Relationship between a matrix, its characteristic polynomial and the convex hull formed by its roots?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-geometry

Suppose I have a matrix $\mathcal{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, whose row sum is zero. The matrix is non-symmetric and has a simple zero as its eigenvalue. Can I comment about the convex hull formed by the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $\mathcal{A}$. Does there exists some relationship between the matrix, its characteristic polynomial and the convex hull formed by its roots?(Like when can it form a 'n'-sided polygon)

Comment: (1) Does "row sum zero" means the sum of all the elements **in each row** is zero? (2) Zero as its eigenvalues = zero is *one of its eigenvalues*?

Comment: (1.)Yes, row sum zero means the sum of all the elements in each row is zero. (2.) Yes, zero is one of its eigenvalues.